Polars: cumsum alternatives
I have below pandas snippet which I want to convert to polars to try, Expected output for polars is same as pandas but failing as cumsum is missing, how to achieve similar output?:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'date': pd.date_range(start='2024-09-01', periods=12),
    'reserved_before': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, 3, np.nan, 3, 4, 5]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['reserved'] = df['reserved_before'].notna()

def assign_group_id(series):
    return (series != series.shift()).cumsum()

df['group'] = assign_group_id(df['reserved'])

def min_max(group):
    non_nan = group['reserved_before'].dropna()
    if len(non_nan) > 0:
        return pd.Series({'min': non_nan.min(), 'max': non_nan.max()})
    return pd.Series({'min': np.nan, 'max': np.nan})

result = df.groupby('group').apply(min_max).reset_index()

df = df.merge(result, on='group', how='left')

df = df.drop(columns=['group', 'reserved'])
df = df.rename(columns={'min': 'block_min', 'max': 'block_max'})

Expected output for polars is same as pandas but failing as cumsum is missing, how to achieve similar output?:
import polars as pl
from datetime import date

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'date': pl.date_range(start=date(2024, 9, 1), end=date(2024, 9, 12), interval='1d', eager=True),
    'reserved_before': [0, 1, 2, None, None, 1, 2, 3, None, 3, 4, 5]
})

df = df.with_columns(
    (df['reserved_before'].is_not_null()).alias('reserved')
)

df = df.with_columns(
    (df['reserved'] != df['reserved'].shift(1)).cumsum().alias('group')
)

min_max_df = (
    df.groupby('group')
    .agg(
        pl.col('reserved_before').min().alias('block_min'),
        pl.col('reserved_before').max().alias('block_max')
    )
)

df = df.join(min_max_df, on='group', how='left')
df = df.drop('group', 'reserved')

Resulting error:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'cumsum'


There is pl.Expr.cum_sum.

However, it seems like you want pl.Expr.rle_id (to directly define the groups).

Why rle_id : Per documentation "The ID starts at 0 and increases by one each time the value of the column changes", this is already the case in my dataframe so rle_id seems not required.

there is also polars.DataFrame.group_by

Here's one approach:
import polars as pl
from datetime import date

pl_df = pl.DataFrame({
    'date': pl.date_range(start=date(2024, 9, 1), end=date(2024, 9, 12), 
                          interval='1d', eager=True),
    'reserved_before': [0, 1, 2, None, None, 1, 2, 3, None, 3, 4, 5]
})

groups = pl.col('reserved_before').is_not_null().rle_id()

pl_df = pl_df.with_columns(
    pl.col('reserved_before').min().over(groups).alias('block_min'),
    pl.col('reserved_before').max().over(groups).alias('block_max'),
)

Explanation

Use pl.Expr.is_not_null and pl.Expr.rle_id to define your groups. IDs will start with 0, not with 1 (as with OP's use of pd.Series.cumsum); irrelevant difference for the purpose.
Use pl.Expr.over to add pl.Expr.min and max.

Equality check original pandas method:
pl_df.to_pandas().equals(df.astype(pl_df.to_pandas().dtypes))
# True


Update for a slightly different logic
Instead of: a group ends where the next value is None
We use: a group ends where the next value is None or where the next value is smaller
pl_df = pl.DataFrame({
    'date': pl.date_range(start=date(2024, 9, 1), end=date(2024, 9, 12), 
                          interval='1d', eager=True),
    'reserved_before': [0, 1, 2, None, 4, 1, 2, 10, None, 3, 4, 5]
})

# desired groups:
# [[0, 1, 2], [4], [1, 2, 10], [3, 4, 5]]

To get groups here, we can use pl.Expr.diff + pl.Expr.fill_null, check < 0, and apply pl.Expr.cum_sum to the result.
groups = (pl.col('reserved_before').diff().fill_null(-1) < 0).cum_sum()

Adjusted output:
shape: (12, 4)
┌────────────┬─────────────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ date       ┆ reserved_before ┆ block_min ┆ block_max │
│ ---        ┆ ---             ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ date       ┆ i64             ┆ i64       ┆ i64       │
╞════════════╪═════════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 2024-09-01 ┆ 0               ┆ 0         ┆ 2         │
│ 2024-09-02 ┆ 1               ┆ 0         ┆ 2         │
│ 2024-09-03 ┆ 2               ┆ 0         ┆ 2         │
│ 2024-09-04 ┆ null            ┆ null      ┆ null      │
│ 2024-09-05 ┆ 4               ┆ 4         ┆ 4         │
│ 2024-09-06 ┆ 1               ┆ 1         ┆ 10        │
│ 2024-09-07 ┆ 2               ┆ 1         ┆ 10        │
│ 2024-09-08 ┆ 10              ┆ 1         ┆ 10        │
│ 2024-09-09 ┆ null            ┆ null      ┆ null      │
│ 2024-09-10 ┆ 3               ┆ 3         ┆ 5         │
│ 2024-09-11 ┆ 4               ┆ 3         ┆ 5         │
│ 2024-09-12 ┆ 5               ┆ 3         ┆ 5         │
└────────────┴─────────────────┴───────────┴───────────┘


cool, this is correct, I made a mistake though in original post example if 'reserved_before': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Then I expect block_min ┆ block_max to be 1 and 3 for first three entry and 1 and 4 for the last 4 entries, basically taking continue value in group. But, my pandas snippet is also not working as intended to going back to it.

IIUC, you mean that a group ends where the next value is None or where the next value is smaller. E.g., if we have: [0, 1, 2, None, 10, 1, 2, 3, None, 3, 4, 5], then 10 is its own group, detached for following group 1,2,3. Correct?

Any continues group as group for example if 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, None, 0, 1, 2 then my groups are 1, 2, 3, 4 and 1, 2, 3 and 0, 1, 2

Yes, in your example, 10 is its own group

Updated the answer to show how you can define groups for the adjusted use case. If the diff should be exactly 1, then use != 1 instead of < 0 (e.g., making 10 its own group as well in the example above).

Note that polars shift() introduces a null value, not a NaN. The following changes to the original code snippet, solve the problems

use cum_sum and group_by
change null values to something else

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import polars as pl
from datetime import date
pl.Config.set_tbl_rows(100)

def assign_group_id(series):
    return (series != series.shift()).cumsum()

def min_max(group):
    non_nan = group['reserved_before'].dropna()
    if len(non_nan) > 0:
        return pd.Series({'min': non_nan.min(), 'max': non_nan.max()})
    return pd.Series({'min': np.nan, 'max': np.nan})

data = {
    'date': pd.date_range(start='2024-09-01', periods=12),
    'reserved_before': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, 3, np.nan, 3, 4, 5]
}

# pandas #
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['reserved'] = df['reserved_before'].notna()
df['group'] = assign_group_id(df['reserved'])
result = df.groupby('group').apply(min_max).reset_index()

df = df.merge(result, on='group', how='left')
df = df.rename(columns={'min': 'block_min', 'max': 'block_max'})
print(df)

# polars #
dfp = pl.DataFrame({
    'date': pl.date_range(start=date(2024, 9, 1), end=date(2024, 9, 12), interval='1d', eager=True),
    'reserved_before': [0, 1, 2, None, None, 1, 2, 3, None, 3, 4, 5]
})

dfp = dfp.with_columns(
    (dfp['reserved_before'].is_not_null()).alias('reserved')
)

dfp = dfp.with_columns(
    (dfp['reserved'] != dfp['reserved'].shift(1).fill_null("NaN")).cum_sum().alias('group')
)

min_max_df = (
    dfp.group_by('group')
    .agg([
        pl.col('reserved_before').min().alias('block_min'),
        pl.col('reserved_before').max().alias('block_max')
    ])
)

dfp = dfp.join(min_max_df, on='group', how='left')
print(dfp)

print(dfp.equals(pl.from_dataframe(df)))

